# Virtual default destructor definition in source file vs in header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Today, during a discussion, a colleague told me it makes a difference if a defaulted destructor is defined in the source file instead of the header file. I cannot recall the details of the conversation (mostly because I couldn't follow his argumentation) but he said something along the lines of:

If the dtor is defaulted in the header file smart pointers could potentially call the wrong dtor. This has something to do with a forward declaration of the type that the smart pointers hold, dll boundaries and the fact that defaulted dtors in headers are inlined.

Lets say we have a base type and a derived type that is part of an API of some dll.

Base.hpp

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Derived.hpp

```
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 

struct Derived : Base
{
    // some arbitrary content

    DLL_API Derived();
    DLL_API virtual ~Derived() = default; // (1)
};
```

If I were to use `Derived` in any way, either inside or outside the dll, would it make a difference if the dtor at **(1)** is defaulted inline (like in the code above) or if it's defaulted in the source file, like below?

Derived.hpp

```
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 

struct Derived : Base
{
    // some arbitrary content

    DLL_API Derived();
    DLL_API virtual ~Derived();
};
```

Derived.cpp

```
Derived::~Derived() = default;
```

Does a scenario exist in which the behavior of `Derived` differs, if the dtor is defaulted inline vs in the source file?

Comment: Inside the class, destructor is defaulted, whereas outside, it is user-provided.

Comment: @Jarod42 I get your point but that doesn't affect the behavior of the program, or does it?

Comment: If a destructor is defined inline, the compiler has more opportunities to actually inline it.     There are some circumstances in which dynamically allocated memory causes problems across DLL boundaries (e.g. the memory is allocated in the DLL, and deallocated outside it) since a different deallocator function may be used.   I don't have references handy, but do recall reading some claims that destructors defined inline or not can cause a different deallocator to be used, but I'm sceptical since I also don't recall seeing any evidence for that sort of claim.

Comment: @Peter I guess this could happen if there are different standard implementations on both sides or if one side overrides operator new/delete.

Answer (score 0):

The explicitly defaulted destructor is `constexpr` (if possible) in C++20.  That’s the only significant difference in the language; it’s also `inline`, but that shouldn’t ever matter.

Comment: Well that's the question. Is there a scenario where inlining causes unexpected side effects?

Comment: @Timo: It shouldn’t in C++17.  In C++20, `inline` has a normative effect in a module, but even then I don’t think it can affect an “empty” destructor meaningfully.